# Combining entries to page numbers

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have entries for an index such as the following:

```
<entry name="a" page="1" />
<entry name="b" page="3" />
<entry name="b" page="4" />
<entry name="b" page="6" />
<entry name="c" page="7" />
```

now I'd like to get something like

```
<index name="a" pages="1 />
<index name="b" pages="3-4, 6" />
<index name="c" pages="7" />
```

Is there some ready to use function for that?

I was thinking of a two pass solution, first put the index entries in a format such as

```
<index name="a" pages="1 />
<index name="b" pages="3 4 6" />
<index name="c" pages="7" />
```

and then turn "3 4 6" into "3-4, 6". The first step is easy:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="index" group-adjacent="@name">
  <xsl:element name="index">
    <xsl:attribute name="name" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="pages" select="current-group()/@page"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

(the attribute 'pages' here could be something different, of course)

Now comes the difficult step, how should I iterate through the list? There must be some clever solution as to check if the next following sibling/@page (I could put the pages into a sequence) is the current @page + 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="entries">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="@name">
      <index name="{current-grouping-key()}">
        <xsl:attribute name="pages">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/xs:integer(@page)" group-by="position() - .">
            <xsl:if test="position() gt 1">
              <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="if (current-group()[2]) 
                                  then (current-group()[1], current-group()[last()])
                                  else ." 
                          separator="-"/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </index>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the input being

```
<entries>
<entry name="a" page="1" />
<entry name="b" page="3" />
<entry name="b" page="4" />
<entry name="b" page="6" />
<entry name="c" page="7" />
</entries>
```

I get the result

```
<index name="a" pages="1"/>
<index name="b" pages="3-4, 6"/>
<index name="c" pages="7"/>
```

Comment: May I ask for (your) help understanding this? The first thing I don't understand is the `group-by="position() - ."` in the innermost `for-each-group` loop. What is the `position()` referring to? The innermost loop? And the `.` is from outer group (does not make sense)? Is `.` the first element in the group?  - Should I as a different question for the explanation?

Comment: The population of the group by is found in the `select` attribute, it is `current-group()/xs:integer(@page)` so it is a sequence of integer values of the `page` attributes. The the `group-by="position() - 1"` for each integer in the sequence computes the expression of `position()` minus that integer, that allows us to find consecutive sequences of integers as with e.g. the population of the group being `3, 4, 6` the group-by computes `1 - 3 = -2`, `2 - 4 = -2`, `3 - 6 = -3` so for the integers `3` and `4` we group them.

Comment: Awesome. Really impressive. And I guess that the expression in `<xsl:value-of...` looks if there is more than one entry in the sequence (2 or more) and if yes, it takes the first and the last, if no, it takes just the only one, right?

Comment: Yes, right, if there is more than one item respectively if there is at least a second item in the group then we output `firstItem - lastItem`, otherwise we output the single item.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      exclude-result-prefixes="xs"      >
      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="entries">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="@name">
          <index name="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:attribute name="pages">
              <xsl:variable name="vAtribVals" as="xs:integer*">
                <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()/@page/xs:integer(.)">
                  <xsl:sort data-type="number"/>
                </xsl:perform-sort>
              </xsl:variable>

              <xsl:sequence select=
                "$vAtribVals[1],
                 for $k in 2 to count($vAtribVals)
                   return
                     if($vAtribVals[$k] - $vAtribVals[$k -1] ne 1)
                       then concat(',', $vAtribVals[$k])
                       else
                         if($vAtribVals[$k+1] - $vAtribVals[$k] ne 1)
                           then concat('-', $vAtribVals[$k])
                           else()
                 "/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </index>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<entries>
    <entry name="a" page="1" />
    <entry name="b" page="3" />
    <entry name="b" page="4" />
    <entry name="b" page="6" />
    <entry name="c" page="7" />
</entries>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<index name="a" pages="1"/>
<index name="b" pages="3-4,6"/>
<index name="c" pages="7"/>
```

**Do note**:

1. The`page` attributes are sorted before further processing, and this allows correct processing even if the `entry` elements do not occur in sorted order in the source XML document.
2. The processing doesn't depend on relationship between integer value and position, which makes it applicable in other cases, where the attribute values aren't integers.